# How to query data where value starts with two possibilities (198 or 190)?

Tags: sql, http, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

the query below returns a list of data I need. I need to make it so that it returns codes that start with 198 **and** 190. I tried simply adding: 'AND ATCOCode STARTS WITH 190' but that simply resulted in no returned data. Currently it returns all data starting with 198 with no problem.

Thanks

https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=**SELECT%20ATCOCode%20FROM%2015n7Rpi190vjrPcmbiT_hRcZ9JbXE8a_I1euHyg%20WHERE%20ATCOCode%20STARTS%20WITH%20198**%20&key=AIzaSyALgi-LNGdOQ-yWXAjnIsBXY7GDUHt2kIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fusion Tables SQL doesn't support OR, so those suggestions aren't going to help. The best you can do is get values starting with 19 and the postprocess the result, at least if it's a string value. If it's a number you can get the same effect by getting values >= 190 and <= 198.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`...where ATCOcode like '198%' or ATCocode like '190%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '198%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE '190%'
```